# Could not get autocompletion on a struts2 jquery json autocompleter tag

Tags: java, jquery, json, autocomplete, struts2

I currently changing may autocompleters which used to work with simple list to json one to be able to link them.

I define a json output from my action (extract from my struts.xml) :

```
<action name="listCompanies" class="web.action.SearchAction" method="getCompaniesAction">
<result type="json">
  <param name="root">companies</param>
</result>
</action>
```

linked to the code (extract of SearchAction):

```
   public String getCompaniesAction() throws Exception{
  if (term!=null && term.trim().length()>1) {
    companies=new ArrayList<KeyValuePair>();
    IServiceReferential serviceReferential = (IServiceReferential)getService(IServiceReferential.class);
    List<ICompany> listDaoCompanies =
        serviceReferential.getCompanies(getUserLoginSession(),term);

    for (Iterator<ICompany> it = listDaoCompanies.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        ICompany company = (ICompany) it.next();
        companies.add(new KeyValuePair(company.getId().toString(), company.getCompanyname()));
    }
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

It sounds to work great : when I ask the json action it works and returns :
[{"key":"1","value":"Comp1"},{"key":"2","value":"Comp2"}]

The autocompleter tag in the jsp looks like :

```
<s:url id="url_companies" action="listCompanies" />
<sj:autocompleter size="1" name="selectCompany" href="%{url_companies}" list="companies" listKey="key" listValue="value" delay="100" loadMinimumCount="2"  onSelectTopics="/autoCompanyChange"/>
```

It fires well the json action but the textbox never proposes me a completion.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the list="companies" attribute from autocompleter